# Software to draw simple conformal mapping diagrams

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

What software is best for drawing the following diagrams?
[mapping half-plane to polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8vrU.png),
[drawing a polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d24N2.png),
[conformal map - preserving angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFZzb.png),
[mapping from half-plane to polygon showing exterior angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EHt7.png),

Comment: Geogebra comes to mind.

Comment: You can also try something like Inkscape, but I think it will take quite a bit of work.